# Как в Android Studio увеличить логи?

Tags: android, json, android-studio

Я делаю запрос на сервер и получаю `JSON`, но `JSON` получается длинным, поэтому отображается не весь логах. Я хочу взять `JSON` и вставить на сервис `Validate`, чтобы посмотреть где какие значения.

Как в Android Studio увеличить буфер логирования?

Comment: единственное что помогло мне в таком случае это вывод джейсона сразу в текстовый файл

Comment: добавьте примерю минимальные.